# Laravel Excel import .ods file issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I tried to import .ods file with Laravel Excel (by Spartner) with queue and stacked with issue. When I run queue from Controller, only one sheet imports correct and after that my ReadChunk job just infinite stacked.

If i try to import .xlsx file, it's works pretty cool, but when i'm trying to import OpenDocument file, i got too many columns, what's not included in my table with two sheets.

**Log::info((new HeadingRowImport))**

```
 0 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'nazvanie',
      1 => 'region',
      2 => 2,
      3 => 3,
      4 => 4,
      5 => 5,
      6 => 6,
      7 => 7,
      8 => 8,
      9 => 9,
      10 => 10,
      ...
     ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      0 => 'nazvanie',
      1 => 1,
      2 => 2,
      3 => 3,
      4 => 4,
      5 => 5,
      6 => 6,
      7 => 7,
      8 => 8,
      9 => 9,
      10 => 10,
...
      1023 => 1023,
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Controller**

```
public function import(array $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        (new CitiesImport)->import($request['file'])->chain([
            new ImportCitiesJob(request()->user()),
        ]);

        toastr()->info(__('Start importing cities from a file'), __('Import'));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**CitiesImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Imports\CitiesSheetImport;
use App\Imports\RegionsSheetImport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class CitiesImport implements WithMultipleSheets, ShouldQueue, WithChunkReading
{
    use Importable;

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            1 => new RegionsSheetImport(),
            0 => new CitiesSheetImport(),
        ];
    }

    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

**RegionsSheetImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Regions\Region;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class RegionsSheetImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation, SkipsEmptyRows
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return Region::firstOrCreate(['name' => $row['nazvanie']]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'nazvanie' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        ];
    }
}
```

**CitiesSheetImport.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Models\Cities\City;
use App\Models\Regions\Region;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class CitiesSheetImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation, SkipsEmptyRows
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return City::firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $row['nazvanie'],
            'region_id' => Region::firstWhere('name', $row['region'])->id,
        ]);
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'nazvanie' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'region' => ['required', 'string', 'exists:regions,name'],
        ];
    }
}
```